# FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value when using tensorboard

Tags: python, compiler-errors, data-visualization, tensorboard

Code works fine until I try to implement tensorboard. Once I add the callback in my `model.fit`, I get the following error:

> FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value
>   training_23/Adam/Variable_7    [[Node: training_23/Adam/Variable_7/read
>   = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_23/Adam/Assign_10"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I tried adding to `tf.global_variables_initializer()` to no avail. I don't know whats missing. Below is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import numpy
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import tensorflow as tf

#random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(6)

NAME = "Test"
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))


# loading load prima indians diabetes dataset, past 5 years of medical 
history 
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("vmlb3.csv", delimiter=",")
test1 = numpy.loadtxt("mpredict.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables, splitting csv data
X = dataset[:,0:4]
Y = dataset[:,4]


# create model, add dense layers one by one specifying activation function
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=4, activation='relu')) # input layer requires 
input_dim param
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) # sigmoid instead of relu for 
final probability between 0 and 1

# compile the model, adam gradient descent (optimized)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics= 
['accuracy'])

# call the function to fit to the data (training the network)
model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 1, batch_size=20, validation_split = 0.3, 
**callbacks=[tensorboard]**)

# save the model
#model.save('weights.h5')
```